# Where were the rock formations in the new wallpaper backgrounds from iOS 14.2 and macOS Big Sur photographed?

Tags: macos, wallpaper

With the release of macOS Big Sur and iOS 14.2 apple put new backgrounds with different rock formations as options for wallpapers (in macOS they are called dome, peak, and valley). Does anyone know where they were photographed or where around these rock formations are? I am thinking Utah or Arizona. Anyone know?
I tried looking to see if there was any exif data for a few of the backgrounds but there wasn't any. Below is one of the wallpapers:

[image]

Comment: This isn’t the sort of practical question the [tour] describes as ideal for the site. Some “guess the app or guess the location” questions can be fun and useful, just be aware that some will down vote them or vote to close.

Answer (score 2):

It is from the White Pocket area formation in Vermillion Cliffs National Monument, Arizona, United States.
[Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vermilion_Cliffs_National_Monument)

Comment: any idea how to find the photographer?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely White Pockets, Arizona!